# Using JPA to connect oracle database,but it still shows Could not load requested class : oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: oracle, hibernate, maven, jpa, ojdbc

I use JPA configuration file，persistence.xml，to set the connection info below：

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" 
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="mydb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.test.vo.Customer</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:1521/orcl" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="cuser" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="cuser" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And I have added ojdbc8.jar in Maven repository：
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3gbc.png

And I import ojdbc8.jar in Maven dependecy：
https://i.stack.imgur.com/anGTF.png

And I also set ojdbc8.jar info in pom.xml：
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd2Qi.png

But when I try to connect to oracle database,it just shows

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

and I see the ojdbc8.jar in Maven dependecy ，the ojdbc8.jar surely contains `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

What happened about this？HOW Can I do to fix it？

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

instead of

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: I have tried this,but it keeps showing the same error...

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Check your URL, which is not correct.

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value=""jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521/myorcldbservicename"/>
```